# BottomSheetDialogFragment in only one pane

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I am trying to implement a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` in my multi-pane application. This is what it looks like now:

```
----------------------------------------
|                        |             |
|                        |             |
|      Fragment          | Fragment    |
|                        |             |
|                        |             |
----------------------------------------
|       BottomSheetDialogFragment      |
----------------------------------------
```

But what I would like to achieve is:

```
----------------------------------------
|                        |             |
|                        |             |
|      Fragment          | Fragment    |
|                        |             |
|                        |             |
|------------------------|             |
|                        |             |
|    BottomSheetDialog   |             |
----------------------------------------
```

My question is: possible doing to achieve that with a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`? Or I would need to have a different approach? If it is possible, can you guys point on the direction of how I can achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you when I worked for a tablet solution with bottom sheets. The solution for me was to add a sub fragment inside Fragment 1. The sub fragment is a normal Fragment using the BottomSheetBehaviour class to establish the same results as the BottomSheetDialogFragment.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#A6000000">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_dialog"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

It is important that you place your BottomSheetBehaviour view inside a CoordinatorLayout.

Then place the following Kotlin code in your fragment. (In this example I am using layout with bindings.)

```
onCreateView() {
   ...
   val bottomSheetBehaviour : BottomSheetBehavior<ConstraintLayout> = BottomSheetBehavior.from(binding.bottomSheetDialog)
   bottomSheetBehaviour.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
   ...
}
```

Then you can add state and slide change listeners for your bottom sheet with `bottomSheetBehaviour.addBottomSheetCallback`.

I found the inspiration from this page: https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `RelativeLayout` to achieve what you want:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_dialog"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_dialog"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fragment_container_1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fragment_container_1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fragment_container_1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```